# IE11 issue click(function()

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#test input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
    $('#test').submit();
  });
});
```

Why this function doen't work on IE11? Is their a workaround to fix this?

like in this thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/40783358

Comment: try live or on method like $('#test input[type="radio"]').on('live',function(){});

Comment: Can you show your HTML? Or make a fiddle where it doesn't work?

Comment: @WisdmLabs that is wrong on a few levels.

Comment: Change click to change.

Comment: is #test built on the fly from the DOM?   If so, you may need to create a higher level attachment point, as in `$(document).on('click','.parentclassoftest', {} ,function(e){ // stuff });`

Comment: @epascarello, live and on method are standard methods available in jQuery. Could you please elaborate more on levels.

Comment: @WisdmLabs live has been deprecated (v 1.7) and removed from jQuery (V 1.9) and if you do have a version that has live, you do not use on with live. Your code is saying to listen for the *onlive* event.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

Comment: use onClick and For onClick event handler I think , 
>By default in IE9+, Internet Options > Security Tab > Internet > Custom Level, scroll down to the Scripting section (near the bottom) and in Active Scripting is disabled, so put a check mark against Enable. And, this resolves the problem and the onclick works!!.

Comment: @Raj active scripting is enabled in IE11 from default.

Answer (score 0):

use this, this will do the trick

```
$(document).on('click','#test input[type="radio"]',function(){
    //your code here
});
```

hope this will helpful to you

Comment: because this is event have the higher level attachment and this will do the trick in every browser

Comment: alright then try this

    $("body").delegate( '#test input[type="radio"]', 'click',function() {
    //your code 
    });